# BigCommerce (stencil) - display specials

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to display all 'special' (or sale) products on a page?  I can't find any reference to specials or products on sale in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Stencil product card price object `{{product.price}}`

```
"product": { 
  "price": {
    "without_tax": {"formatted": "$150.00","value": 150},
    "rrp_without_tax": {"formatted": "$250.00","value": 250},
    "saved": {"formatted": "$100.00","value": 100},
    "tax_label": "Tax"
  }
}
```

The effective price of the product is the sale price. This sale price is associated to the "without_tax" property. The regular price is then displayed in a new property called "non_sale_price_without_tax".

```
"product": { 
  "price": {
    "without_tax": {"formatted": "$123.00","value": 123},
    "non_sale_price_without_tax": {"formatted": "$150.00","value": 150},
    "rrp_without_tax": {"formatted": "$250.00","value": 250},
    "saved": {"formatted": "$127.00","value": 127},
    "tax_label": "Tax"
  }
}
```

You can then use conditional logic, knowing this, to do something to denote sale price such as:

```
{{#if price.non_sale_price_without_tax}}
     … display on-sale strikeout pricing
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - unfortunately I can't even get any products to display at all (asked this question before attempting as I assumed it'd be easier than it is).  I've added `products:` to the frontmatter but `{{#each products}}...{{/each}}` still returns nothing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Depending on the store's Tax settings, you may need to use a different if check (`non_sale_price_without_tax` vs `non_sale_price_with_tax`). 
To make sure you cover all cases, I recommend changing the if check to:
```{{#or price.non_sale_price_without_tax price.non_sale_price_with_tax}}
  ...stuff in here
{{/or}}```